# Network Chat in C#

Tags: c#, networking, listbox, chat

I've done something like a little chat in C# to communicate with friends at school so the teacher doesn't notice.

Now I discovered a problem:
I used a listBox as the mainly 'Chatwindow' so the messages themselves are displayed in a 'fixed row'.

My question at this point is the following:
Does anyone of you have a better idea than a listBox as the Chatwindow?
I use the listBox in WindowsForms.

I also could activate 'Wrap text' in listBox but then there is another problem:
I'm not able to copy a message a friend sent me and this is something I realy need.

Does somebody have an idea to solve my problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Use line breaks when outputting messages to the UI?

Comment: No not yet, but maybe I will soon.

Comment: Well, if the output has no line breaks and you want it to have line breaks, adding line breaks *seems* like a reasonable solution to that problem.

Comment: Thats not the main problem. The main problem is that I can't copy the content

Comment: Definitely use a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control.  For multiple chats you'd simply create new instances of the **Form** that contains the RichTextBox: `frmChat chat = new frmChat(); chat.Show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Rich text editor or any HTML Editor to use it as chat window. I personally had used RTE first then replaced it with HTML Editor

Comment: I want it as a 'WinForm'. So I can open a different chat for every person and dont need to open hundreds of HTML Editors

Comment: Whats the problem in opening different HTML Editors?

you can dynamically create a copy of winform for every chat

Comment: Or You have only one option Rich Text Editor which is also good and suitable for you